# compare timestamp with timestamp in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I generate a current timestamp like this:

`<?php echo time(); ?>`

The result is:

`1589352983`

Now I woule like to get all data from my mysql database where my row "time" is > than my current timestamp value.

The problem is, that my timestamp value has not the correct time zone.
How can I set the time zone for my timestamp ?

I need GMT+02:00

**UPDATE**

I insert data into my mysql database.
At this moment a timestamp will automatically create by mysql and will stored in the row "time"

In my php script I start a query where my php timestamp (which can be in the past, because it was generated minutes before) is < timestamp of my database

`SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE`time`> 1589354666 ORDER BY`time`DESC`

1589354666 = the timestamp from my php script.

But here I get all my data because the timestamp is converted:
13.05.2020 09:24:26

But it will compare with the value:
13.05.2020 07:24:26

Comment: Set php timezone to match mysql

Comment: and how can I do this ?

Comment: set timezone for php date/time functions e.g. `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

Comment: Can I take a step back and ask why you're generating the time in php rather than just passing the MySQL command CURRENT_TIME (or NOW() as that'd probably be more useful) as a WHERE clause when retrieving your data to start with?

Comment: sorry but this does not solve my issue. once again: please look at my first post, I will update more details in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone in php before you run `time();`
This way php will return time for that timezone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>
```

You can find a list of all supported timezones [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)